Why can't we use Householder transformation to do SVD directly? Instead we need to go through bidiagonalization first.
In SVD, given a matrix A, the two matrix series on the left and right in the Householder transformation respectively are not required to be the same. So I guess it maybe okay to use the Householder transformation to diagonalize (instead of bidiagonalize) A.
As a reference, a similar question, the answer to which I'm satisfied with, was raised about the Householder process in resolving the eigenvalues of a matrix. The answer to that question is the right matrix would destroy the zeros that were introduced by the left matrix. Because we had to use two same matrices.
Ref:

https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~bindel/class/cs4220-s16/lec/2016-03-11-notes.pdf
Following the same thinking path leads to this question.
